# A quotient stack $[X/G]$ and irreducibility of $X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.
Let $X$ be a variety over $k$ and $G$ be a algebraic group over $k$ acting on $X$.

**Question**

If the quotient stack $[X/G]$ is irreducible, then is $X$ also irreducible ?

Any comment welcome !

Edit: the original question is from line 8 on page 208 of
https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=jcrcPtr8aFMC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=irreducible+quotient+stack&source=bl&ots=UxLrr9puIN&sig=ACfU3U2wQ9htPKj1_PYkWJQLS-Fpp26Klg&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRot3li7HoAhU5yIsBHRZSB8wQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=irreducible%20quotient%20stack&f=false

Comment: What definition of variety does this book use? Usually they are *assumed* integral, hence irreducible. If not, you can just quotient a disjoint union of two copies of a space by an action of $\mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: Do you want to assume $G$ is connected?

Comment: In the book you refer to the group $G$ is  connected and $[X/G]$ is smooth, so $X$ is smooth and irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for the comments ! @abx, Could you give me a detailed reason for that?

Comment: And I'm sorry I didn't make any assumptions in detail.

Comment: Pull back $X\rightarrow [X/G]$ by a surjective morphism$P\rightarrow [X/G]$ with $P$ irreducible. The pull back is a principal $G$-bundle over $P$, hence irreducible.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Is there one more question you want? How can I get irreducible $ P $ and surjection$ P → [X / G]$ ?

Comment: Stacks Project, Lemma 104.3.1.

Comment: Thank you many times.

Comment: @abx i'm slightly confused: doesn't that lemma merely assure that you can find P irreducible and with dense image in [X/G]? Anyway, it seems to me you can just argue using the fact that X->[X/G] is open with irreducible fibers (being a G-torsor), as you would if [X/G] were a scheme.